# Flow declaration file with CommonJS

Tags: javascript, commonjs, flowtype

How do I write a proper Flow declaration file when using CommonJS like this?
This is in a file named demo.js.

```
// @flow
function product(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
exports.product = product;
```

Here is what I tried.  This is in a file named demo.js.flow.

```
// @flow
declare export function product(a: number, b: number): number;
```

Flow still complains that the parameters a and b are missing annotations in the previous file.

Comment: Did you add your declarations folder to your `.flowconfig`? https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#pointing-your-project-to-declarations

Comment: actually that shouldn't matter since you're using .js.flow...it's in the same folder as demo.js i'm assuming?

Comment: Right Andy, it is in the same folder. It seems this isn't documented well anywhere yet unless I just haven't found the right docs.

Answer (score 0):

Following [the documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html#example-writing-a-custom-libdef), I would try with:

```
declare module 'demo' {
  declare module.exports: {
    product(a: number, b: number): number;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried exactly that and it didn't work. It would be great if someone could point me to a simple example that works.